# Properties of dot products and gradients

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck on part (d) and (e) of the following problem

If ${\bf A}=x^2z{\bf i}+yz^3{\bf j}+3xy{\bf k}$, ${\bf B}=y^2{\bf i}-yz{\bf j}+ 2x{\bf k}$, and $\phi=2x^2+xy$, find:
(d) ${\bf B}({\bf A }\cdot \nabla)$
(e) $(\nabla \cdot {\bf A }){\bf B}$

I'm stuck on (d), but I think I found (e):
(d)
\begin{align*}
{\bf B}({\bf A }\cdot \nabla) &= {\bf B}\left(x^2z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+yz^3\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+3xy\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)\\
&=y^2\left(x^2z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+yz^3\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+3xy\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right){\bf i}-yz\left(x^2z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+yz^3\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+3xy\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right){\bf j}+ 2x\left(x^2z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+yz^3\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+3xy\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right){\bf k}
\end{align*}

(e)
\begin{align*}
(\nabla \cdot {\bf A }){\bf B} &=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}{\bf i}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}{\bf j}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}{\bf k} \cdot x^2z{\bf i}+yz^3{\bf j}+3xy{\bf k} \right){\bf B}\\
&=(2xz+z^3){\bf B}\\
&=(2xz+z^3)y^2{\bf i}-(2xz+z^3)yz{\bf j}+(2xz+z^3)2x{\bf k}\\
&=2xy^2z+y^2z^3{\bf i}-(2xyz^2+yz^4){\bf j}+(4x^2z+2xz^3){\bf k}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: not clear why they give you a definition of $\phi$. Both, part (d) and (e) seem right!

Comment: I just copied and pasted it off my LaTeX'd homework.  The problem has 5 parts.